# can i have an alias for the result table of inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I have an alias of the result of the join of 2 tables? So that I can call the result of the table in its alias name.

```
SELECT emp_table.Name, dept_table.dept
FROM dept_table
inner join emp_table
on emp_table.dept_id = dept_table.dept_id;
```

Comment: And your problem is... ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT YourAlias.Name
      ,YourAlias.dept
FROM (SELECT emp_table.Name, dept_table.dept
      FROM dept_table
      INNER JOIN emp_table
        on emp_table.dept_id = dept_table.dept_id) AS YourAlias;
```

Or use a CTE:

```
;WITH YourAlias AS
(
     SELECT emp_table.Name, dept_table.dept
     FROM dept_table
     INNER JOIN emp_table
        on emp_table.dept_id = dept_table.dept_id
)
SELECT Name, dept
FROM YourAlias;
```

More information on CTE [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Not exact but assume column alias and table alias name like this

```
SELECT e.Name as aliasname, d.dept as aliasdept
FROM dept_table d
inner join emp_table e
on e.dept_id = d.dept_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put in a Derived Table:

```
select dt.Name, dt.dept
from
 (
   SELECT emp_table.Name, dept_table.dept
   FROM dept_table
   inner join emp_table
   on emp_table.dept_id = dept_table.dept_i
 ) dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server and many other DBMSs you can wrap the join query in parentheses and put an alias after the closing parenthesis.

```
select joined.foo
from
(
select a.foo, b.bar
from
table1 a
inner join
table2 b
on a.baz = b.baz
) joined
```